# Search all docx files with python-docx in a directory (batch)

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have a bunch of Word `docx` files that have the same embedded Excel table. I am trying to extract the same cells from several files.

I figured out how to hard code to one file:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document(r"G:\GIS\DESIGN\ROW\ROW_Files\Docx\006-087-003.docx")
table = document.tables[0]
Project_cell = table.rows[2].cells[2]
paragraph = Project_cell.paragraphs[0]
Project = paragraph.text

print Project
```

But how do I batch this? I tried some variations on `listdir`, but they are not working for me and I am too green to get there on my own.

Comment: A little Python tip, don't capitalize a variable unless it represents a class (which is rare as you're beginning). This way when you see a capitalized identifier you can be pretty sure it represents a class. So `Project_cell` would become `project_cell` and `Project` would become `project` (or perhaps more precisely `project_name`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you loop over all of the files will really depend on your project deliverables.  Are all of the files in a single folder?  Are there more than just `.docx` files?

To address all of the issues, we'll assume that there are subdirectories, and other files mingled with your `.docx` files.  For this, we'll use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) and [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.splitext#os.path.splitext)

```
import os

from docx import Document

# First, we'll create an empty list to hold the path to all of your docx files
document_list = []       

# Now, we loop through every file in the folder "G:\GIS\DESIGN\ROW\ROW_Files\Docx" 
# (and all it's subfolders) using os.walk().  You could alternatively use os.listdir()
# to get a list of files.  It would be recommended, and simpler, if all files are
# in the same folder.  Consider that change a small challenge for developing your skills!
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r"G:\GIS\DESIGN\ROW\ROW_Files\Docx"): 
    for name in files:
        # For each file we find, we need to ensure it is a .docx file before adding
        #  it to our list
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, name))[1] == ".docx":
            document_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))

# Now create a loop that goes over each file path in document_list, replacing your 
# hard-coded path with the variable.
for document_path in document_list:
    document = Document(document_path)        # Change the document being loaded each loop
    table = document.tables[0]
    project_cell = table.rows[2].cells[2]
    paragraph = project_cell.paragraphs[0]
    project = paragraph.text

    print project
```

For additional reading, here is the documentation on [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os.listdir#os.listdir).

Also, it would be best to put your code into a function which is re-usable, but that's also a challenge for yourself!

Comment: Thank you, the code worked well and was very easy to understand.  I do think I am missing something though.  I ran it and it returned data on the first file in the folder and stopped.   I am extracting multiple cells to add values to a geodatabase using arcpy.da.InsertCursor I didn't include the full code because that part  works just fine and I thought it would distract from my main question but I could if it is useful.

Comment: It would really depend on how the rest of your code is setup to work.  If you just run the above, it should print out a separate line for each file with the desired `paragraph.text`.  Instead of printing, you could append it to a list, or add it directly.  I would confirm the above works (as described), and then start a new question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: your code works as designed, I'll look into applying into my process.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code above get you the data you need, all you need to do is read the files from the disk and process them.

First let's define a function that does what you were already doing, then we'll loop over all the documents in the directory and process them with that function.

*Edit the following untested code to suit your needs.*

```
# we'll use os.walk to iterate over all the files in the directory
# we're going to make some simplifying assumption:

# 1) all the docs files are in the same directory
# 2) that you want to store in the paragraph in a list.

import document
import os 


DOCS = r'G:\GIS\DESIGN\ROW\ROW_Files\Docx'

def get_para(document):
    table = document.tables[0]
    Project_cell = table.rows[2].cells[2]
    paragraph = Project_cell.paragraphs[0]
    Project = paragraph.text
    return Project

if __name__ == "__main__":
    paragraphs = []
    f = os.walk(DOCS).next()
    for filename in f:
        file_name = os.path.join(DOCS, filename)
        document = Document(file_name)
        para = get_para(document)
        paragraphs.append(para)

    print(paragraphs)
```